# Unable to install dependencies of R in google cloud platform (GCP)?

Tags: r, google-cloud-platform, dependencies, package, gcp-ai-platform-notebook

I need to install dependencies in AI notebook platform in GCP. I tried to use notebook as well as terminal but getting error. 
 This is what i get when i try to install in GCP

[image]

And this is the error for terminal

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Jupyter user does not have the root access because you are supposed to [install packages locally](https://www.osc.edu/resources/getting_started/howto/howto_install_local_r_packages). For example (be aware that you can replace /tmp with a local directory):
`install.packages("ggplot2", lib="/tmp")`